# What format can I use in Excel to display both date and time in system formats

Tags: microsoft-excel, date-time, cell-format

I need to display both date and time in system date and time formats.
I know that `[$-0xf800]` means the system long date format and `[$-0xf400]` means the system time format, but `[$-0xf800][$-0xf400]` doesn't work.

What format can I use to display both date and time in system formats?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the version of Excel and what OS you are using. Have you tried the options available for cell formatting which automatically adjusts to system formats?